# Send commands to another network

Tags: c#, web-services, network-programming

I am trying to write a monitoring tool to monitor some information
It will gonna work on azure normally. So i gonna host the database on azure also the webservice will be hosted at azure.

On the client's i read from the config file how many time's he need to update the information to the azure database ( with the webservice on azure ).

Now i want to send also some commands to the client itself. Like start service, .... what is the best way to do that?
How can i send it from a website that is hosted on the azure platform?

Comment: Do you have a VPN to your Azure server?

Comment: Nope, don't have a VPN to the Azure server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider implementing a WCF service at the client as well. The Azure side of your software could call operations from this service when it needs to instruct the client to do something.

The WCF service at the client should be something simple,hosted in a Windows Service or in your actual client (whatever it is... win forms, console, etc).

Comment: So then i need to configure for every "customer" a webservice on there client that i can call. And give them some Parameters.

Comment: @Svekke: When you say "configure" I think about IIS. But this is nothing that complicated. At most you need to setup the endpoint to bind to the correct IP. You may even do that from an UI, so no dirty configuration work would be needed.

Comment: What i mean is that i need to store on my azure system every ip from my client. What with firewalls?

Comment: @Svekke: You don't need to do that. The clients can ping, for example at startup, the server to let them know their IP/port. The server can then call them back on that address. But you have to make sure firewalls are open and traffic is allowed for this to work. Easier than configuring all clients.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no VPN, it sounds like you may have a problem with hosting a WCF service on the client. If the client is behind a firewall, you would have to modify the firewall configuration to allow your server to connect to this service.

Last time I had to do a service like this, I used [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). The server maintains a queue of messages to be sent to the client. Your client connects to the web service and requests any available messages. If messages are available, the server returns them. If not, the server leaves the request open for some time. As soon as a message arrives, the server sends it down the already-open connection. The client will either periodically time out/reconnect or send a keep-alive message (perhaps once per minute) in order to keep the connection alive in the intervening firewalls.